# How to change edge of pages in Beamer

Tags: beamer

I'm using long math formulas and need to get smaller edges in Beamer presentation. I mean how I can get all environments such as definition, theorems, proofs starting at the same position as frametitle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `text margin left=<length>` and text `margin right=<length>` for `\setbeamersize` you can change the margins; in the example I set them both to 0pt just for illustration purposes:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=0pt,text margin right=0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{theorem}
text
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]